# ArcMap Framework - Scroll bars in Layout View went missing. How to bring them back?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have encountered a minor yet very annoying layout view change. All of a sudden my scroll bars in Layout View bars have disappeared.  I also no longer have the small layout view, data view, refresh and pause buttons which are normally a part of the the scroll bars. I now have to go to the main menu to switch my view from layout to data. However the scroll bars appear in data view. 
I probably toggled something off accidentally but where? There must be a simple way to bring them back. Anyone? 
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

View menu - Scoll Bars, you'll want to check that option.